# App Store does not show my app after approval

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I developed iOS app, and I uploaded binary of my app on 19th August 2013.

Today(23rd August 2013) I got mail from Apple saying that "your app is **Ready for sale**" with Green dot in my iTunes Connect. but it doesnot show any links to my app in **in App Store** in my iTunes Connect account

This is my first version of app,

Here is screenshot of my rights and pricing section from my iTunes Connect account.

How should I live my app in app store or it will be automatically live in the store ?

[image]:
***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Did you mistype the upload date there?

Comment: Just wait, it takes time.

Comment: The App Store lives in the cloud. It takes awhile to propagate. I'm assuming you picked at least one store (country).

Comment: Here is my Status history,   August 19, 2013 07:22
**Waiting For Review**
.
.
.

August 23, 2013 06:48
**In Review**


August 23, 2013 07:10
**Processing for App Store**

August 23, 2013 07:14
**Ready for Sale**

Comment: yes i have selected one country

Comment: I've had to wait a few hours between approval and seeing it appear in the updates list.

Comment: it is already more then 24 hours but app is still not LIVE.. :(

Comment: If you are that desperate, call Apple support. They will give you all the info you need...

Comment: PLEASE accept this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18467328/2057171

It actually worked. Changing data caused Apple's propagation code to be called again, normally apps should go live in 30-60 minutes, anything more is a bug in my book (60+ apps submitted over 6 years, never had it take longer)

Comment: You should seriously change your accepted answer. I can't believe this has been a but since at least 2013.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I might be wrong, can't remember connect that well, been a few months since I last published an app.

Check the following:

1. Price Tier Selected
2. That you have selected some countries stores where you would like the app to be sold (distributed)
3. Lastly it might take about 24 hours for the app to propagate to all app stores.

Check again tomorrow on the store. Your release date does look in order since it is a historic date.

Comment: it is already more then 24 hours but app is still not LIVE.. :(

Comment: yes, I have selected. Thanx for helping bro my app got LIVE now it tooks more then 48 hours.

Comment: Same for me, my app still isn't in the store after 3 days.  I'm dying...  with anticipation, of course.

Comment: Every App relies on the "touch-points" from where a user can click and land on the App's Download page in App Store. As a fix, although not exactly what is required, it is better to use the direct link to your App in iTunes/AppStore by clicking or copying the link of "View in App Store" option within your iTunes Connect's App details.

Comment: Based on my experience, the following is the order in which the links above available: 1. Mail from Apple would contain a small right arrow next to your app name, this would open it in iTunes (even when Apps menu doesn't exist in iTunes 12), 2. App Store link on your MyApps page / Open link on App Store, 3. Search on the App Store

Answer (score 49):

Just happened to me too.

Go back into app description, and make a simple
edit. Save it.

Two minutes later it will be ready for sale.

Comment: I did this and changed the availability date to current date and our app finally showed up in App Store! It seems like App Store visibility has a bug.

Comment: Not sure if it was a coincidence or not, but my app has just appeared after editing the description. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this possible to do this still? I can‘t edit the app description since I submitted my binary. It‘s grayed out :-( Anyone can help?

Comment: this is really awesome... just awesome :D

Comment: After more than 5 . years developing iOS apps this happen to me and this answer help me solving the error, in 2019, SoftWare sometimes is SoWeird

Answer (score 11):

From Apple's FAQ:

> My app status is Ready for Sale but I cannot see my app on the App
> Store. Why?  The following factors could prevent your app from showing
> up on the App Store:
>
> - Make sure to check the status of your agreements. If the agreement
>   status is Pending Contract, you may have to agree to the PLA or Paid
>   Applications agreement or complete the associated bank and tax
>   information for that agreement.
> - Make sure the availability date
>   provided in the Rights and Pricing section is prior to today's date.
> - If the date provided in the Rights and Pricing section is in the past,
>   make sure you made your app available in at least one App Store
>   territory.
> - If your app was scheduled to go live within the last 24
>   hours, the app may still be updating in the App Store cache. Once the
>   24-hour caching window has passed, close and open iTunes and search
>   for your app again. You can also click View in the App Store from the
>   More tab on your app's page in My Apps.
>
> If you have checked the factors above and the app is still not on the
> App Store, contact us.

Comment: What is the URL of that Apple's FAQ to check it from the official source?

Comment: @JaimeMontoya: As far as I can remember it wasn't linkable. I think I saw it after tapping some "Contact Apple" button in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

As "Apfelsaft" says, any pending contractual conditions can block the availability of the app in the store. This is my case.

[image: Screen shot from my iTunes connect account]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
No need to wait, just go to the App Description, make a small update.
Then in less than 5 minutes, the app is available.