# App not showing up in App Store after a week of ready for sale

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes

Last week I submitted my 3rd app to the App Store and everything went smoothly. However, after the status became "ready for sale" it has not shown up on the App Store after an entire week.

I read on these forums that it takes at most a day, so is something wrong here?

Thanks!

Ps: In reply to comments, "availability" is set to 8th of August 2015, and the app is set to be available in every territory.

Comment: What is your "availability date"?

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409552/app-store-does-not-show-my-app-after-approval